# commit() should be called before retrieving the values for out parameters?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, procedure, autocommit

While writing java JDBC code to call a stored procedure I am using `con.setAutoCommit(false);` My question is what is the difference in the below approaches:

Approach-1:

```
        con = DBConnection.getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt= con.prepareCall("{call updateEmp(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
        stmt.setInt(1, id);
        stmt.setString(2, name);
        stmt.setString(3, role);            
        stmt.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

        stmt.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
        //read the OUT parameter AFTER commit
        String result = stmt.getString(6);
```

or Approach-2:

```
        // Read the OUT parameter BEFORE commit
        String result = stmt.getString(6);
        con.commit();
```

Comment: The difference is that the commit is one line downer...

Comment: @alfasin Sometimes humor is a really good idea. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that in cases when out parameter is a simple type, it's to greater extent a matter of style.  However, out parameter can be,  for instance, a cursor.  In case of autocommit, a commit operation occurs only when  all of the result sets that are returned by cursor type output parameters or by the stored procedure are closed. If commit issued before cursor completely fetched , data consistency is questionable.  To avoid such ambiguity , I'd suggest committing/rolling back transaction after all out parameters are read.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would depend on whether the stored procedure you're calling does its own commit or not. I would expect an update procedure that takes in params, and sets out params to do a commit or rollback internally.

In that case, calling setAutoCommit(true) or calling con.commit() would have no effect, and the out parameter would have a value regardless of when you call stmt.getString(6).  If there's no commit in the stored procedure itself, I would expect your out parameter to be null if you call con.commit() after you call stmt.getString(6).

Comment: "I would expect your out parameter to be null if you call con.commit() after you call stmt.getString(6)." - sure about that ?

Comment: Now that you mention it, probably not - The proc could return a value even if it hasn't committed the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The major difference is that you're holding a transaction open longer than necessary. You should always try to commit as quickly as practically possible, in order to minimize the possibility of blocking other transactions. Especially if you're doing something like transferring a BLOB or large text field that could potentially tie up a lot of transaction log space (as well as take more time to transfer across the wire).

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in exception handling. If getString throws an exception, then the following commit will not execute. The consequences depend on whether there are any changes in the current transaction**. If you were to trace the two versions of the code (where no exception is ever thrown) and then compare the two trace files, you would not be able to tell which version of the code created each trace unless you left markers of some kind (or kept the spids for each user process).

You have to ask yourself the question: do I want to commit even if exceptions are thrown? Then you'll know how to write the code.

** Your connection always has a transaction open. Some transactions have changes and others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Just summing up the above answers in one answer for a quick summary:

1- If commiting, before all out parameters are read, data consistency is questionable. So here approach-2 is not advisable.

2- Suppose an exception occurs while reading the output parameters, then the transaction won't be committed. On the other hand, if we want the transaction to be committed without caring about the out parameters, we can commit before reading them.

3- In approach-2 we are blocking a transaction for longer time. In above sample code, its not a big deal but it may be a problem where we are doing lots of things before committing.